# Comparing two fields on Google maps fusion table API

Tags: javascript, sql, json, maps, google-fusion-tables

I have been trying to compare two fields on a fusion table, from the google maps API. I have done a few maps using this API, but I now I don't know what to do.
I have three columns(`MURATURAPORTANTE`,`CALCESTRUZZOARMATO`,`ALTROMATERIALE`), and when one is bigger than the other two, I need to show the polygon in a different color.
I create my `google.maps.FusionTablesLayer` with the following options:

```
layer = {
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: tableId
  },
  templateId: 2,
  styles: [{
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: color1,
      fillOpacity: 0.4
    }
  }, {
    where: "CALCESTRUZZOARMATO>MURATURAPORTANTE AND CALCESTRUZZOARMATO>ALTROMATERIALE",
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: color2,
      fillOpacity: 0.4
    }
  }, {
    where: "ALTROMATERIALE>CALCESTRUZZOARMATO AND ALTROMATERIALE>MURATURAPORTANTE",
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: color3,
      fillOpacity: 0.4
    }
  }]
};
```

The result, is a map where only the last element of the `styles` array is represented:
[screenshot of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS2fF.png).
If I change the `where:` field to compare the fields of the table with just numbers, it works, so it must be the comparison between two fields that causes the problem.

If you want to take a look at the table, here is the ID: `1wV7ezib1-KkxVz1hjKyQli2E-fTB2ro487UvQL32`.
Thanks in advance!